# Does the callonce function executes the feature again if i use use in this function multiple times in same feature file and different scenarios

Tags: karate

I have multiple scenarios in one feature file in my project. One of the feature file creates tokens. I want to call this feature only once at the start of the test and then use the tokens in the other feature without executing the token feature again and again.

Answer (score 0):

No. `callonce` is "once-only" within a `Feature`.

Please spend some time and read the documentation. It will answer all your questions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks